# no transaction is in progress since spring migration to 4.3.3

Tags: spring, hibernate, migration

I am facing an issue and I can't seem to find a solution.

I am migrating a project from Hibernate 5.1.1 to 5.2.2 and Spring from 4.1.0 to 4.3.3.

Using weblogic, when I try to deploy my ear I get a TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress.

This happens on a bean that is supposed to make a lot of queries to the database, and the method is annotated @PostConstruct.

It was working fine before, I updated my hibernate configuration according to the migration guide and I can't seem to find the solution.

This is the modified configuration for Hibernate 5.2.2 :

```
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">jta</prop>
<!-- How to produce transaction -->
<prop      key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>
```

This is an extract of the server log :

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3428) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1395) [hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1391) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:144) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:932) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:487) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy408.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

It was working fine before my migration attempt and I suppose it is related to the fact that the bean is initialized but the transaction is closed.

What is strange is that when I debug the method, I am able to get the first few calls to the database but it fails later on.

In both cases I am using :

```
getHibernateTemplate().executeWithNativeSession(new HibernateCallback<List<E>>()
```

Has anyone of you encountered this kind of problem?

I googled days long and I can't find a single answer corresponding to this problem (btw. this also happens on my Junit tests)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cheers!

Comment: There is (and was) no garantuees that transactional proxy is already created in the `@PostConstruct` method. So you might have an unproxied instance or setup in there. Hence it will fail. Generally doing those things in a `@PostConstruct` method isn't the best place (better use an `ApplicationListener` with a `ContextRefreshedEvent` or if you really want to  keep it, do manual tx management by using a `TransactionTemplate`.

Comment: Yes I understand, but that's not the problem.What I am trying to figure out (without success) is why it worked with the previous versions of Spring and Hibernate and why it is now broken. I would like to figure out what configuration needs to be done without altering my code.

Comment: If it worked it was more luck then that it should have worked in the first place. Next to that depending on what you exactly used might now be cleaned up (earlier versions of Spring, especially the hibernate integration, contained workarounds/hacks, to make things work, many of those have been removed in favor of the proper session/entitymanager use in newer versions of hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem while migrating to Hibernate 5.2.2 and Spring 4.3.3.

In my code I wasn't necessarily using a @Post construct method but I had the same exception *no transaction is in progress* when calling a simple *Get* method from the database.

I found [this link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14364) on the Spring forum, and at the end of the discussion it was pointed out that the problem happens in some transactions, but not in others.

For my case, when I annotated my transaction with `REQUIRED` propagation the problem disappeared (it was `SUPPORTS` at th beginning).